# Extremely slow layout inflating in android

Tags: java, android

I'm refactoring android application. Before first start I've made quite a lot of changes and at some step it became sluggish in some places. Here's one of such places.

I have a tab layout with several Fragments. Some Fragments work fine, but this one is sluggish. It simply takes some "Brands" from android room database and fills ListView by using Adapter.

Fragment onCreateView method :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_ll, container, false);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout);
        mListView = linearLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view1, i, l) -> {
            Brand brand = mAdapter.getItem(i);
            if(brand == null) return;
            brand.setSelected(!brand.isSelected());
            mBrandsViewModel.upsertBrand(brand);
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Adapter getView:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Logger.i(getClass().getName(), "Called getView");
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            Logger.i(getClass().getName(), "Got inflater");
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        Logger.i(getClass().getName(), "View inflated");
        TextView brandNameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.brandNameTextView);
        CheckBox brandCheckBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.brandCheckBox);
        Brand brand = brands.get(position);
        brandNameTextView.setText(brand.getBrandName());
        brandCheckBox.setChecked(brand.isSelected());
        brandNameTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        return convertView;

//        if (convertView == null) {
//            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
//            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, null, true);
//
//        }
//        Brand brand = brands.get(position);
//        CheckedTextView textView = convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
//        textView.setText(brand.getBrandName());
//        textView.setChecked(brand.isSelected());
//        return convertView;
    }
```

XML of R.layout.brand_list_item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/brandNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/brandCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's logcat when the Fragment is being created

```
03-17 07:25:55.249 4181-4181/some.package.here D/AbsListView: onDetachedFromWindow
03-17 07:25:55.309 4181-4181/some.package.here D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-17 07:25:55.449 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Called getView
03-17 07:25:55.449 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Got inflater
03-17 07:25:55.729 4181-4181/some.package.here D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1461K, 33% free 9585K/14264K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
03-17 07:25:56.359 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:25:56.909 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:25:56.919 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: View inflated
03-17 07:25:56.979 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Called getView
03-17 07:25:56.979 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Got inflater
03-17 07:25:57.749 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:25:58.289 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:25:58.299 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: View inflated
03-17 07:25:58.359 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Called getView
03-17 07:25:58.359 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Got inflater
03-17 07:25:58.979 4181-4181/some.package.here D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3488K, 43% free 8144K/14264K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
03-17 07:25:59.119 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:25:59.659 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:25:59.669 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: View inflated
03-17 07:25:59.739 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Called getView
03-17 07:25:59.739 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Got inflater
03-17 07:26:00.499 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:01.049 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:01.059 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: View inflated
03-17 07:26:01.089 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Called getView
03-17 07:26:01.089 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Got inflater
03-17 07:26:01.669 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:02.079 4181-4181/some.package.here D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1523K, 40% free 8669K/14264K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
03-17 07:26:02.399 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:02.419 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: View inflated
03-17 07:26:02.479 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Called getView
03-17 07:26:02.479 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Got inflater
03-17 07:26:03.239 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:03.789 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:03.799 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: View inflated
03-17 07:26:03.869 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Called getView
03-17 07:26:03.869 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Got inflater
03-17 07:26:04.449 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:05.039 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:05.059 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: View inflated
03-17 07:26:05.099 4181-4181/some.package.here D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1536K, 36% free 9142K/14264K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
03-17 07:26:05.239 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Called getView
03-17 07:26:05.239 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: Got inflater
03-17 07:26:06.019 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:06.559 4181-4181/some.package.here W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-17 07:26:06.569 4181-4181/some.package.here I/some.package.here.preference.adapters.BrandAdapter: View inflated
03-17 07:26:06.679 4181-4181/some.package.here I/Choreographer: Skipped 679 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I've noticed that something happens during inflation, but I can't figure out what exactly and how to solve sluggish performance. Also I don't understand why `res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml` is being called.

Important things to know:

- every sluggish place in the app has `W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue...`
- when I use built-in item `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` instead of my own in adapter's getView method (commented out part) then everything works like a charm.

Edit: ViewHolder pattern doesn't solve the problem. I'm observing the same message in logcat: `W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue...`
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are initialising view for each list item. You can either replace listview with recycler view else use view holder in you list adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            Logger.i(getClass().getName(), "Got inflater");
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Brand brand = brands.get(position);
    viewHolder.brandNameTextView.setText(brand.getBrandName());
    viewHolder.brandCheckBox.setChecked(brand.isSelected());
    viewHolder.brandNameTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView brandNameTextView;
    public CheckBox brandCheckBox;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        brandNameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.brandNameTextView);
        brandCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.brandCheckBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not my case. I know ViewHolder pattern and tried it. Still sluggish. And still same message in logcat. Also, I mentioned that when I switch to built-in list_item then everything works fine even without viewHolder

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think I found the reason.

During refactoring I moved the app from android.support libs to androidx lib, which is apparently not friendly to old platform devices (mine is quite old)

How I came to this conclusion:

1. Took demo-project from [this](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-1-5959aa49337c#.grjjjreo2) article (which uses android.support libs)
2. Compiled, ran, everything works fine
3. Changed gradle from android.support to androidx and voi là:

```
03-18 07:34:48.789 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0006
03-18 07:34:49.359 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-18 07:34:49.899 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences W/Resources: Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x4e4 "res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml" a=2 r=0x109004d}
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.CompoundButton.getButtonDrawable, referenced from method androidx.core.widget.CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2762: Landroid/widget/CompoundButton;.getButtonDrawable ()Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.CompoundButton.getButtonTintList, referenced from method androidx.core.widget.CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonTintList
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2763: Landroid/widget/CompoundButton;.getButtonTintList ()Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.CompoundButton.getButtonTintMode, referenced from method androidx.core.widget.CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonTintMode
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2764: Landroid/widget/CompoundButton;.getButtonTintMode ()Landroid/graphics/PorterDuff$Mode;
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.CompoundButton.setButtonTintList, referenced from method androidx.core.widget.CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2780: Landroid/widget/CompoundButton;.setButtonTintList (Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;)V
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.CompoundButton.setButtonTintMode, referenced from method androidx.core.widget.CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintMode
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2781: Landroid/widget/CompoundButton;.setButtonTintMode (Landroid/graphics/PorterDuff$Mode;)V
03-18 07:34:49.909 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
03-18 07:34:50.209 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.View.setTooltipText, referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.TooltipCompat.setTooltipText
03-18 07:34:50.209 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2127: Landroid/view/View;.setTooltipText (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
03-18 07:34:50.209 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
03-18 07:34:50.219 20235-20235/de.jakobulbrich.preferences I/Choreographer: Skipped 130 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Same `W/Resources: Converting to boolean:` and same message from Choreographer

Comment: Same here, after upgrading my app to android 11 layouting gets slower.

Comment: I'm just struggeling with the same "error". I found that using AndroidX with Fragments or AndroidX with an Activity extending AppCompatActivity was REALLY slow when navigating to it (5-8 seconds!) on old devices - changing the Activity in question from "AppCompatActivity" to "Activity" made it much faster on my old Samsung S5 mini. Got no solution for a Fragment as of now.